# How to change edit date format (Date picker) in flutter

Tags: flutter

In the current date picker ui, the date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`. I want to change to `DD/MM/YYYY`.  Please guide.

```
showDatePicker(
initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
helpText: ' ',
currentDate: DateTime.now(),
context: context,
initialDate: selectedDate,
firstDate: DateTime(1960, 1, 1),
lastDate: DateTime(2200, 12, 31),
builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
  return Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF1CA357))),
    child: child,
  );
},
```

);

[image: date picker ui]

Comment: Read about it here https://medium.com/@prafullkumar77/flutter-format-a-date-with-locale-using-dart-c6fa400c8a53

Answer (score 8):

Try to use this (eg. for `de` locale):

Add internationalization processing and support in pubspec.yaml:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Add internationalization support in the top-level control MaterialApp:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('de', 'DE'),
    Locale('en', 'US'),
  ],
  locale: Locale('de'),
  ...
)
```

Then set the `locale parameter of [showDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) as follow:

```dart
final date = await showDatePicker(locale: Locale('de'));
```

Comment: Setting Locale('de', 'DE'), changes calendar UI language to German. Is it possible to change input format without changing calendar language? 
For example I want to use English and dd.mm.yyyy format in edit date input

Answer (score 0):

Add `Puspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter
```

Add the following code in `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';    
        
void main() async {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
        //home: SplashScreen(),
        // List all of the app's supported locales here
        supportedLocales: [
            Locale( 'in' , 'IN' ),
            Locale( 'en' , 'US' ),
            Locale( 'de' , 'DE' ),
        ],
            
        localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
            
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
            for (var supportedLocaleLanguage in supportedLocales) {
                if (supportedLocaleLanguage.languageCode == locale.languageCode && supportedLocaleLanguage.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                    return supportedLocaleLanguage;
                }
            }
            return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        locale: Locale('in'),
        home: Home(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: AppColor.primaryColor,
            accentColor: AppColor.accentColor,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.